# Rake task to drop dev database also drops test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Not sure if this is expected behavior but whenever I run

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development
```

It also drops my test db

```
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development
Dropped database 'my_app_development'
Dropped database 'my_app_test'
```

I only want to drop my dev db. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This should help you https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27299 & https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37042

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's not possible without a custom workaround if I'm reading this correctly.

Comment: Yes, It looks like that. The first one is very old and it is closed without solution linking to second issue. The second issue is still open.

Comment: You could always write your own rake task or just use `dbdrop` (pg) or `mysqladmin` (mysql) directly. The [job performed by `db:drop`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/99a4620a19d48e1a1ffa514d9f930862c7f16e3e/activerecord/Rakefile) isn't exactly rocket science.

Comment: Afaik this is by design. The test database is always dropped and recreated before running the tests anyway (by default).